# Rails- MiniMagick commands not working

Tags: windows, ruby, image-manipulation, imagemagick

I'm running windows xp and I've got MiniMagick and ImageMagick installed (latest versions). I'm now using the console to test out that everything works. Using the ms command prompt image magick works no problem. I'm testing this by using the identify command. Now, when I try to use MiniMagick from the console by entering

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.new('image.jpg')
```

It returns

> MiniMagickError, "ImageMagick command ("identify \"input.jpg\"") failed: {:status_code => #"'identify' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\noperable program or batch file.\n"}

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

When you tried the identify command in the command prompt, were you in the directoy where image magick is installed? If so, try it from a different directoy. If that does not work, you have to add the directory with the image magick executables to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, i've taken these steps and found that the path was setup properly. I've tried restarting the WEBrick server but the same problem occured. I can run the exact command from the console and it will execute (although the temporary file can't be found)